# Using Selected Context of TableSelectDialog as a Model for Table

Tags: sapui5

I'm trying to set `selectedContexts` parameter of `sap.m.TableSelectDialog` as a model for `sap.m.table`.

I made sure that the `selectedContext` is not empty with the following code:

```
MessageToast.show("You have chosen " + aContexts.map(function (oContext) {
                        return oContext.getObject().documentPN;
                    }).join(", "));
```

First I tried to set binding context for the table:

```
this.byId('myTable').setBindingContext(aContexts[0]);
```

I have also tried to fetch `selectedItems` array and set it as a data for the model.

```
let oItems = oEvent.getParameter("selectedItems");
let oTable = this.getView().byId("myTable");
let oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
oModel.setData(oItems);
oTable.setModel(oModel);
```

Both approaches didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to solve the problem. Here is the code:

```
let oTable = this.getView().byId("myTable");
let oModel = new JSONModel();
let arr = [];
aContexts.map(function(oContext) {
        arr.push(oContext.getObject());
});
oModel.setData(arr);
oTable.setModel(oModel);
```